# css grid with implicit rows and aspect-ratio problem

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve a css grid with various squares that scrolls sideways:

https://codepen.io/flapusmog/pen/poOqrWa

The problem is that the aspect-ratio of the squares outside the original width gets squashed, and loses their proportions. It's as if the width of the grid container doesn't grow with it's content. It seems to me that the width of the grid container is not expanding:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,30vh);
  height:100%;
  
/*   not working */
  width:auto; 
}

.cell {
  outline:1px solid red;

  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}

.content {
  aspect-ratio:1/1;
}

.c2 {
  grid-row:span 3;
  grid-column:span 3;
}

.c3 {
  grid-row:span 3;
  grid-column:span 3;
}

.break {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell c3">
    <div class="content">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell c2">
    <div class="content">
      helo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      helll
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      helll
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell break">
    <div class="content">
      sort of a title
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      helll
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      helll
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell c3">
    <div class="content">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell c2">
    <div class="content">
      helo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      helll
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The problem (happens at the edge of the original width limit)
[image: Problem]

how can i make sure they all stay square? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `cell` class:

```
aspect-ratio: 1; 
display: flex;
```

The aspect-ratio attribute forces every cell to be square, and the flex display keeps the content from overlapping on each other.

You can also remove `width:auto` from `.grid`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference: https://codepen.io/flapusmog/pen/xxampPe.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want. It obviously makes a difference, all the cells are now square, and the width of the container grows along with its content.

Comment: Oh i see, your fix works in brave (webkit) but not in Firefox. https://i.imgur.com/Gtpbmms.png

Comment: Try copy pasting your code to actual files and running them with firefox. It is possible that by loading the whole page properly, it fixes your problem.

Comment: thanks for the tips, but its the same - i'll try and see if i can get the attention of someone good at firefox quirks

Comment: For the time being (begining 2023) it seems that the only way is to avoid aspect-ratio. Related FF bug here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1719273. Instead I'll hardcode the dimensions in the squares. It's unfortunate since I have to work with absolute values, but at least it works.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you can resolve the problem by adding the aspect-ratio to the cells and not to the content.

Comment: Then the width doesn't seem to be respected at all https://codepen.io/flapusmog/pen/xxampLB